# App crashed when using QBSimpleSyncRefreshControl in tableview pull to refresh

Tags: ios, crash, pull-to-refresh

I'm using tabview controller, one of the view controller having table view I use QBSimpleSyncRefreshControl for pull down refresh, its working fine in first time load tab controller,
when I logout my user, I reload my Tab controller (root view controller) that time app crashed unexpectedly.

This is the code I'm using

in tableview controller

```
QBSimpleSyncRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[QBSimpleSyncRefreshControl alloc] init];
refreshControl.delegate = self;
self.myRefreshControl = refreshControl;
[self.tvTableView addSubview:self.myRefreshControl];
```

i did in logout

```
 UIStoryboard *board  = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
 UINavigationController *Tabctrl = [board instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vcInitialViewNavId"];
 UIWindow *window = AppDelegate.window;
 [window addSubview:Tabctrl.view];
 window.rootViewController = Tabctrl;
```

If I block this line

```
[self.tvTableView addSubview:self.myRefreshControl];
```

App working fine, If unblock this app crashed when logout (Reload root view controller)

Can anyone help for this.

---

Full code Here:

view.h File

```
@interface MyTCView : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, QBRefreshControlDelegate>
{
   // some declaration here
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tvTableView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) QBSimpleSyncRefreshControl *myRefreshControl;
```

view.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    FeaturedItemTitle = @"";

    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];

    AppDelegate = (TCAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    board = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    QBSimpleSyncRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[QBSimpleSyncRefreshControl alloc] init];
    refreshControl.delegate = self;
    self.myRefreshControl = refreshControl;
    [self.tvTableView addSubview:self.myRefreshControl];
}

- (void)refreshControlDidBeginRefreshing:(QBRefreshControl *)refreshControl
{
     [self GetDetails];
}

-(void) GetDetails
{
    // Calling web service here 

  NSString *strURL = @"URL HERE";

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: strURL];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:methodType];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:delegate];

    if ( theConnection ) {
        //Connection successful
        receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    } else {
        //Failure
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
}

//*** HTTP Connection ***//

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [HUD hide:YES];
    [self ShowAlertMessage:ServerErrorMsg Tilte:@""];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *error;

    NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

        // Array of data get from Res(NSDictionary)

        [tvTableView reloadData]; // Tableview Reload

        [collView reloadData]; // Collectionview reload

        [self.myRefreshControl endRefreshing];

        [HUD hide:TRUE]; 
}
```

Comment: @rmaddy: I post some code here please check.

Comment: where is your root controller i guess the Navigation controller, do you have any? and you can not subView the controller

Comment: Yes my Rootviewcontroller is Navigation controller only. sorry I cant get you, what change need to be there for solve this issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the right way to logout a navigationcontroller based application, just use the standard way to load the rootController using

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: If I did like this, My controllers not refreshed the loaded data's in still in the controllers.

Comment: do you have tableView for displaying data?

Comment: Yes, I have tableview in viewcontroller

Comment: SO you can call tableView reloadData

Comment: Yes I call reload function 
- (void)refreshControlDidBeginRefreshing:(QBRefreshControl *)refreshControl
{
     [self GetMyTCDetails];
}

But problem occur when I logout user, I try to reload rootviewcontroller, That time only app will crashed.